# Composer install fails over command line

Tags: composer-php, cpanel

I seem to be able to connect to SSH on my CPanel and run the installer, however access to the "installer" fails, thus denying the installation of composer. Any ideas?

```
[mememigf@server188 home]$ wget https://getcomposer.org/installer
--2016-07-01 01:49:27--  https://getcomposer.org/installer
Resolving getcomposer.org... 87.98.253.108, 2001:41d0:a:7b19::2
Connecting to getcomposer.org|87.98.253.108|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 293630 (287K) [application/octet-stream]
installer: Permission denied

Cannot write to “installer” (Success).
[mememigf@server188 home]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is already a file in your home directory with the name "installer" that you don't have permission to write to.

Test if that's the case using this command

```
ls -l | grep installer
```

The suggested installation method for composer is as follows

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Taken from the composer installation page
https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: Unfortunatley, this doesnt work in an SSH environment.

Comment: It does. I have done it many times. It does sound like simply permission issues. If you don't have root access you should discuss permissions with your host

Comment: Do you have php-cli installed?